# Duo Security (two-factor authentication) PHP SDK on Plogger Gallery Admin

Tags: php, security, two-factor-authentication

I'm looking for some much needed help in setting up [Duo Secuirty](https://www.duosecurity.com)'s [PHP Web SDK](https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_php) for two-factor authentication for my [Plogger](http://www.plogger.org/) gallery's admin section. I've tried several approaches, but the [documentation](https://www.duosecurity.com/docs/duoweb) is very sparse, and somewhat incomplete.

I cannot post my exact attempts here for obvious security reasons, but I just need a general outline of how to modify the original login page code to get duo two-factor authentication working on my admin section.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Plogger can be found - [HERE](http://www.plogger.org)

I'm using version : 1.0 RC1

Thanks in Advance!

-James A.

Comment: Seriously? nobody has even the slightest clue?